# How to fix "npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142" error in Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm using Windows 10. I want to use Angular 4 on my system. When I run node -v and npm -v it displays the version. But when I execute the statement npm install -g @angular/cli, i gives :

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142C:\Users\VAISHU\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\VAISHU\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@9.1.9 postinstall C:\Users\VAISHU\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@9.1.9
updated 1 package in 15.317s
```

when I enter the command ng -v, it shows :

```
Available Commands:
  add Adds support for an external library to your project.
  analytics Configures the gathering of Angular CLI usage metrics. See https://angular.io/cli/usage-analytics-gathering.
  build (b) Compiles an Angular app into an output directory named dist/ at the given output path. Must be executed from within a workspace directory.
  deploy Invokes the deploy builder for a specified project or for the default project in the workspace.
  config Retrieves or sets Angular configuration values in the angular.json file for the workspace.
  doc (d) Opens the official Angular documentation (angular.io) in a browser, and searches for a given keyword.
  e2e (e) Builds and serves an Angular app, then runs end-to-end tests using Protractor.
  generate (g) Generates and/or modifies files based on a schematic.
  help Lists available commands and their short descriptions.
  lint (l) Runs linting tools on Angular app code in a given project folder.
  new (n) Creates a new workspace and an initial Angular app.
  run Runs an Architect target with an optional custom builder configuration defined in your project.
  serve (s) Builds and serves your app, rebuilding on file changes.
  test (t) Runs unit tests in a project.
  update Updates your application and its dependencies. See https://update.angular.io/
  version (v) Outputs Angular CLI version.
  xi18n (i18n-extract) Extracts i18n messages from source code.

For more detailed help run "ng [command name] --help"
```

I don't know whether I have to uninstall Node js, and install again. Please suggest any solution. Thank You.

Comment: Its a warning, not an error. There is a github link in the warning log. Start by reading the linked site.

Comment: Have you read that warning? It tells you you are using a deprecated package. Either update it or ignore that warning

Comment: Thank you  for  replying. To update, canI run the  npm install -g @angular/cli again until the warning  doesn't get displayed?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same message installing node unirest module on Ubuntu 20.04 but when I ran the command a second time the warning was no longer displayed.

**First time with warning:**

```
user@server:~/project$ npm install -S unirest
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

added 55 packages, and audited 57 packages in 2s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

**Second time without warning:**

```
user@server:~/project$ npm install -S unirest

up to date, audited 59 packages in 617ms

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was trying to install angular using:
nmp install -g @angular/cli

I needed to install it using sudo as :
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

The same issue "depricated warning" was thrown, but ignored in the end and the other commands were executed succesfully.

```
moses@dev:~/Projects/prod_qa/project_ui$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
/usr/local/bin/ng -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@12.2.10 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

? Would you like to share anonymous usage data with the Angular Team at Google under
Google’s Privacy Policy at https://policies.google.com/privacy? For more details and
how to change this setting, see https://angular.io/analytics. (y/N)
```